# Handling updated records in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs

Every day the 'user' table from oracle get dumped into HDFS. The dump contains only the recent changes(inserts and updates) that have been made after the previous dump. Now I wanted to load all the daily dumps using PIG into a relation and join this with the Transaction file using the 'userid' field. The problem is with the updated records. Same user can have multiple records. I only want to use the most recent user record while doing the join. How can we do this. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group the updates file, order it by date and select the first one and then join the on that. Something like the code below should get you the newest update

```
A = LOAD 'user_updates'...;
A_Users = GROUP A BY user_id;
A_TOP = FOREACH A_Users {
  sorted = ORDER A BY update_time DESC;
  top_one = LIMIT sorted 1;
  GENERATE top_one;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Instead of doing this every time, Is there an incremental way to do it? It might pose a problem when the data set becomes very large. Is there a better way to do it than the one mentioned in this link http://grokbase.com/t/hive/user/10688hfg6z/how-to-apply-rdbms-table-updates-and-deletes-into-hadoop

Comment: since the updates table is small you can do a replicated join so the smaller table will be copied over and the bigger one will not move  see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/perf.html#Specialized-Joins

Comment: Another way would be to store it in HBase which supports random read-write (i.e. you can update the specific records that changed)

Comment: Thank You. Will try the replicated join